# cookie being set for www.example.com instead of example.com

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, cookies

I have java application running under tomcat which is fronted by apache webserver.
In my code I set cookie domain as
.example.com

but still my cookies shows up under www.example.com instead of under example.com in the client browser. What is so strange google analytics cookies shows up under example.com but my own code cannot store cookies under example.com?

Apache server is setup such that requests for example.com shows up as www.example.com in the client browser address bar if that is related to the issue ? I do need this otherwise different session id are generated for example.com and www.example.com which is bad for my applicaton.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache server is setup such that
>   requests for example.com shows up as
>   www.example.com in the client browser
>   address bar if that is related to the
>   issue ?

I am not 100% sure, but this looks like the root of the problem. How does Apache make the client browser to display www.example.com instead of example.com? Most probably, by redirecting each request for example.com to www.example.com. When the browser processes redirection, it sends a request for www.example.com and from that point on thinks that it is working with www.example.com.

Now, what happens when there is a Set-Cookie in the response header? It will obviously treat it as coming from www.example.com. There is no way a browser would allow such cookie to set its domain to .example.com because it would be a security problem. Imagine that mysite.somefreehosting.com sets a cookie for the domain .somefreehosting.com. Then someothersite.somefreehosting.com would receive this cookie which may lead to a lot of trouble. The standard specifies that such cookie should be rejected, but I wouldn't be surprised if some browsers are smart enough to handle such cases and to treat .example.com as www.example.com.

To be sure, I recommend that you check what exactly your site sends to the browser by sending a request with something like lwp-request script. You'll see what redirections are happening and what headers are actually set in the response, like this:

```
alqualos@ubuntu:~$ lwp-request -sSed http://google.com/
GET http://google.com/ --> 301 Moved Permanently
GET http://www.google.com/ --> 302 Found
GET http://www.google.co.il/ --> 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 18 Dec 2010 18:54:57 GMT
Server: gws
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255
Expires: -1
Client-Date: Sat, 18 Dec 2010 18:54:57 GMT
Client-Peer: 173.194.37.104:80
Client-Response-Num: 1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=368e9cfd56643257:FF=0:TM=1292698497:LM=1292698497:S=s-Jur84NgaNH5Mzx; 
  expires=Mon, 17-Dec-2012 18:54:57 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.il
Set-Cookie: NID=42=bZ6goDV_b2MiWlTMONwiijaON5U_TBGB2_yNheonEwA1GVLU77EhyfUhk9Wvj70xTFrpvGy4s_aBp1UZtvRRnsnYjacjz_UVx0_iSr9R3nYXMyRtwkS5qV98_Egb16pZ; 
  expires=Sun, 19-Jun-2011 18:54:57 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.il; HttpOnly
Title: Google
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: I checked sending that request and I get the same sequence of GET as google: GET --> http;//example.com 301 Moved Permanently
http;//www.example.com GET  --> 302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://www.example.com/user/uid --> 200 OK. The only difference google is 302 Found.

Comment: The message is not important. The code is all that matters. Your last URL got parsed by SO engine, but I take it is http;//www.example.com/user/uid? Well, in this case you won't be able to set cookies for .example.com for security reasons. Why would you want that anyway?

Comment: Sorry ya I meant  http;//www.example.com/user/uid. Since the linux command lwp does not accept cookies my code would redirect to  http;//www.example.com/user/uid and that is expected. But if the cookies are enabled on the client browser, this redirect would not happen. My grails application has URL mapping which says any requests to '/' which means requests to example.com would be automatically redirected to example.com/user/index (for user authentication/cookie checks) . I am not sure how grails does this internally it may not be even a redirect.

Comment: example.com or www.example.com? My point is that if the browser displays www.example.com in the address bar, it won't accept cookies for .example.com (since the request-host name doesn't match), and that's expected. Note that for further debugging you can send cookies with lwp-request, using `-H 'Cookie: sessid=12345'` like syntax.